# Chrome flashes black screen when using css transition rotate

Tags: google-chrome, css

Transition rotate causes chrome to flash black screen. Is it a Chrome bug (works fine in Safari) or it can be fixed with some clever css.

```css
div { 
  width:200px; 
  height:200px; 
  position:relative; 
  background:#ddd;
}

span { 
  display:inline-block; 
  position:absolute; 
  top:40px; 
  left:40px; 
  width:20px; 
  background:#007; 
  height:10px; 
  -webkit-transition: all .5s; 
}

div:hover > span { 
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); 
}
```

```html
<div>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

Example [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/CMzQm/).

The problem with this problem is that it doesn't occur every time so you'll have to hover the gray square several times and you should see the screen blinking in black.

Tested in: 
Chrome 16.0.912.75 
Chrome Canary 18.0.1010.0

Works fine on: 
Safari 5.1.2 (6534.52.7)

All test on Snow Leopard

Comment: It doesn't happen in Chrome whatever or Chrome Canary on Windows 7.

Comment: Ok. I found chromium bug report for this: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=87512

Comment: same problem here: Chrome: 16.0.912.77 on MACOS and it does the same when you use scale

Comment: Chrome 21 has the same problem, windows 7.

Comment: Semi-relevant.. The black screen is currently occuring in 2018 with filter:hue-rotate

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can fix this by forcing compositing to stay on by giving `-webkit-transform: translate3D(0, 0, 0)` to the parent of the transformed element.

```css
div { width:200px; height:200px; position:relative; background:#ddd; -webkit-transform: translate3D(0, 0, 0)}
span { display:inline-block; position:absolute; top:40px; left:40px; width:20px; background:#007; height:10px; -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .5s; }
div:hover > span { -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); }
```

```html
<div>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Check out the fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/UHLFF/

Comment: That seems to do the trick. Thanks! +1 for webkit only solution to webkit (or chrome) only bug.

Comment: Could you give any insight into how you figured this out please? Would love to know!

Comment: I had the same issue and found the workaround on a chromium bug ticket.

Comment: That "fix" brake LOTS of other functionalities, like fixed animations relative to screen